# displaying a year calendar

Tags: php, arrays, calendar, string-comparison

I'm quiet new.... and I'm still messing up a lot with the code.

I have done an array:

```
$months = array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");
```

And then I have a switch statement that returns the number of days for each month:

```
function month_length($month) {

    $leap_year = date("L");

    switch ($month) { 
        case "January":    return $max = 31;       
        case "February":   
               if ($leap_year === 1) {
                return $max = 29;
            } else {
                return $max = 28;
            }
        case "March":      return $max = 31;
        case "April":      return $max = 30; 
        case "May":        return $max = 31; 
        case "June":       return $max = 30; 
        case "July":       return $max = 31; 
        case "August":     return $max = 31; 
        case "September":  return $max = 30; 
        case "October":    return $max = 31; 
        case "November":   return $max = 30;
        case "December":   return $max = 31;
        default:           return $max = "wrong number";
    }     
}
```

Is there any way I can compare if any object of the array matches with any case?

Let me clarify; so at the moment, I need to set a $current_month to let php know what case I want to display, and I want to be able to display all months for each year.

Does anyone know what am I trying to say? So I guess I need to compare a string from the array months with the case of the switch statement, but... how? As I don't want to have to compare one per one :S

Thank you!!!!

Comment: You mean something like [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) ?

Comment: The [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function may be of great help to you.

Comment: mmmm I don't think so...although I don't know much. How do I loop with foreach to check if the value matches? :S my god this is so difficult! let me added in jsfiddle!!

Comment: great.... does not have php... do you know an editor where I can add my code and show you the link?

Comment: castis that is my problem. At the moment I am using date, and it detects as current month October, but I want to display all months, not just the current one, so I need to loop through each $months array, but then it needs to know how many days have each month, which happens in the switch statement

Comment: http://phpfiddle.org/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution with `foreach`:

```
foreach($months as $month) {
   echo "The month with name $month has ".month_length($month)." days.<br>";
}
```

Comment: :S it doesn't work with month.... check here, and see what I've done. Probably I've done a huge mistake.... but I can't see it!!! 

http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/bc3fdcb7806a982b2982

Comment: arg sorrry I've just understood it!!

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

This code will print a table calendar. It will display 7 days per row for 5 columns. days from 30/31 to 35 are filled with the next or previous days of the month to keep the week aspect.

Hope it helps.

```
 function renderMonth($displayM, $displayY){

        $daysOfWeek = array (
                'Mon',
                'Tue',
                'Wen',
                'Thu',
                'Fri',
                'Sat',
                'Sun'
        );

        $dateUtil = new DateTime ( $displayY . "/" . $displayM . "/01"  );
        $year = $dateUtil->format ( "Y" );
        $week = $dateUtil->format ( "W" );

        $week_start = new DateTime ();
        $week_start->setISODate ( $year, $week );
        $nextDay = clone $week_start;

        $i = 1;
        $weekdays = 7; // how many days do we display per row
        $currday = 1; // current week day
        $daysno = 35; // number of display dates

        $calendar = '<table class="event-calendar">';
        $calendar .= "<thead>";
        $calendar .= "<tr>";
        foreach ( $daysOfWeek as $day ) {
            $calendar .= "<th>$day</th>";
        }
        $calendar .= "</tr>";
        $calendar .= "</thead>";
        $calendar .= "<tbody>";
        while ( $i < $daysno ) {
            if ($i == 1) {
                $calendar .= '<tr>';
                $calendar .= '<td>' . $nextDay->format ( 'd M' ) . '</td>';
            }
            $currday ++;
            if ($currday > $weekdays) {
                $calendar .= '</tr>';
                $calendar .= '<tr>';
                $currday = 1;
            }
            $nextDay->add ( new DateInterval ( 'P1D' ) );
            $calendar .= '<td>' . $nextDay->format ( 'd M' ) . '</td>';
            $i ++;
            if ($i == $daysno) {
                $calendar .= '</tr>';
            }
        }
        $calendar .= "</tbody>";
        $calendar .= "</table>";
        return $calendar;
    }


    echo renderMonth("10", "2015");
    echo renderMonth("11", "2015");
    echo renderMonth("12", "2015");
```